# PHP - "if" in "while" problems to alternate html table rows colour

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

```
$banana=0;
$view = mysql_query('SELECT ......') or die ('Encountered an error.') ;
while($rows3=mysql_fetch_array($view))
{
    $total_price2=$rows3['qty']*$rows3['number'];
    $banana = $banana + 1;

    if ($total_price2!=0)
    {   
        if ($banana %2 ==0)
        {   
            echo "<tr class=\"alt\">";
        }   
        else
        {
            echo "<tr>";
        }   
        echo "<td>".$rows3['member']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$rows3['payment']."</td>";
        echo "<td>$".number_format($total_price2,2)."</td>";                
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Problems:**

- The "banana" alternates the colour of the table row (class="alt") by using modulus (%) to check if banana is a odd number.
- Not Working, I see the browser is self-closing the opening `<tr>` tag.

eg:

`<tr><td>person</td><td>data</td><td>$10.00</td></tr>`

`<tr class="alt"></tr>` (Repeats in this fashion)

## UPDATE

I have discovered that the reiterating `banana` always returns ODD NUMBERS: 1 , 3, 5, etc

> **MySQL is not running correctly**

`SELECT table1.member, table1.paid, table1.payment,table2.qty,table3.number FROM table1,table2,table3 WHERE table1.member = table2.member AND table1.payment="fruit"`

It is giving me wrong data like so:

1. person1 $10.00
2. person1 $0.00
3. person2 $10.00
4. person2 $0.00

etc

Comment: the code seems to be correct. there's some other error.

Comment: Agreed; should absolutely work. But, try doing this instead of IF statement: printf( "<tr class=\"%s\"">, ($banana %2 ? '' : 'alt') );

Comment: Yes I am puzzled. The css table colour row is definetly working too.

Comment: When `$total_price2 == 0` there should be no `<td>`s inside that particular row (because of your `if` statement). Maybe that's what you're seeing?

Comment: Don't you want the entire row wrapped in the condition `if ($total_price2!=0) { `, otherwise you are emitting blank rows if that condition is not true.

Comment: One more thing: it's highly recommended you use meaningful variable names. Doesn't seem to be the case with `$banana`...

Comment: @mellamokb I tried putting the `banana if` INSIDE `if ($total_price2!=0)` 
No luck on that too.

Comment: Can you provide the EXACT html that is being generated? Your example is obviously not it because your have two `tr` tags with the `alt` class in a row.

Comment: @jasonlfunk Exact HTML
`<tr><td>person</td><td>data</td><td>$10.00</td></tr>`

`<tr class="alt"></tr>`

Repeats in that fashion

Comment: @Lee That seems like the expected output if `$total_price2` equals 0 for the second row.

Comment: @jasonlfunk I have moved `banana if` under `$total_price2 if` - this was the original plan, not working also.

Comment: @Lee Try my update and let me know the results, please.

Comment: @Lee I don't think your problem lies elsewhere then the provided code.

Comment: Could it be the Query:
`SELECT table1.member, table1.paid, table1.payment,table2.qty,table3.number FROM table1,table2,table3 WHERE table1.member = table2.member AND table1.payment="fruit"`

Comment: @Lee Have you tried your query in php my admin or via command line? Does it return what you expect? How is `table3.number` evaluated, because there is no mention of table3 in your WHERE clause?

Comment: @Blake `table3` is "unit price" number that is used to multiple later. There is something wrong in my Query because it is not return what I want. Trying to find out, I update the question shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work.  You're only opening the table row if `$total_price2!=0`.  It seems you should only output the closing `</tr>` tag inside that IF block.

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$banana=0;
$view = mysql_query('SELECT ......') or die ('Encountered an error.') ;
while($rows3=mysql_fetch_array($view))
{
    $total_price2=$rows3['qty']*$rows3['number'];

    if ( !$total_price2)
        continue;

    $banana = $banana + 1;

    if ($banana %2 ==0)
    {   
        echo "<tr class=\"alt\">";
    }   
    else
    {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    echo "<td>".$rows3['member']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rows3['payment']."</td>";
    echo "<td>$".number_format($total_price2,2)."</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Although how do I fix my Query? Its resulting each name twice, with the price 10 or 0. See above update.

Comment: also what is the "!" mean in `if ( !$total_price2)`. why doesn't this if statement have {} brackets?

Comment: I don't know what your query is... please add it to your question.

Comment: The `!` means a "falsey" value, like 0, and you don't need brackets for a single-line statement.  Both are personal preference.  You could write it `if ($total_price2 == 0) { continue; }`

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this for a debug first:

`echo "<tr class=\"alt\">&nbsp;";`

My guess is that you have no data contained in your <tr> and is being squished to 0 px tall by your browser.

EDIT: I'm not entirely sure giving a class to your <tr> will filter down into the <td> based on certain browser DOM parsing. Whenever I do a zebra row, I'll assign the class to the <td>. I'm no designer by any standard, though. :)

Humor me and try this please:

```
$banana=0;
$view = mysql_query('SELECT ......') or die ('Encountered an error.') ;
while($rows3=mysql_fetch_array($view))
{
    $total_price2=$rows3['qty']*$rows3['number'];
    $banana++;
    if ($banana % 2 == 0) {   
        $td_class = "alt";
    } else {
        $td_class = "";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    if ($total_price2!=0) {     
        echo "<td class='{$td_class}'>".$rows3['member']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='{$td_class}'>".$rows3['payment']."</td>";
        echo "<td class='{$td_class}'>$".number_format($total_price2,2)."</td>";                            
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: thx for your help, i will try it out first in the morning. 3.15 am here x.x     zzzzzzz

Comment: no luck again :( the Modulus keeps returning Odd numbers, skipping the even numbers (class="alt").

Comment: @Lee we're going to need more of your code then. Something else must be influencing `$banana`, also what was the html print from my code?

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails, you could just use CSS:

```
tr {background-color: blue;}
tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: red;}
```